# PlotStyle with nested list

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

Simple Question from a Stumped Rookie:

Using ListPlot, I can't get PlotStyle to look below the first level of a nested list to assign individual saturation values for each point; it assigns the first three saturation values to the first three groups of points.

```
pts = {{{0.10, 485}, {0.22, 495}, {0.35, 500}},
       {{0.94, 739}, {2.95,814}}, {{3.47, 802}}};
saturationList = {1, .5, .2, .5, .3, .7};
colors[sat_] := Hue[1, sat];
myPlotStyle = Map[colors, saturationList];
ListPlot[pts, PlotStyle -> myPlotStyle]
```

I ultimately want to assign different colors to each group while assigning unique saturation values to each point.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be better to use `Graphics`

```
pts = {{{0.10, 485}, {0.22, 495}, {0.35, 500}},
       {{0.94, 739}, {2.95, 814}}, {{3.47, 802}}};
saturationList = {.5, .2, .5, .3, .7};
col = {Red, Blue, Green, Brown};
Graphics[Table[{PointSize[Large], 
 Lighter[col[[i]], saturationList[[#]]], Point[pts[[i]][[#]]]} & /@
 Range[Length[pts[[i]]]], {i, Length[pts]}], AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Or you can use `Hue` as

```
Graphics[Table[{PointSize[Large], Hue[i, saturationList[[#]]], 
 Point[pts[[i]][[#]]]} & /@ Range[Length[pts[[i]]]], {i, 
 Length[pts]}], AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Hue[h,s]` to distinguish between groups via `h` and within groups via `s`:

```
pts = {{{0.10, 485}, {0.22, 495}, {0.35, 500}},
       {{0.94, 739}, {2.95,814}}, {{3.47, 802}}};
saturationList = {1, .5, .2, .5, .3, .7};

sl = MapIndexed[Thread[{#2[[1]], #}]&, Internal`PartitionRagged[saturationList,
               Length /@ pts], {1}];

newpts = Style[{#, #2}, Hue[#3/ Length[pts], #4]] & @@@ (Join @@ (Join @@@ # & /@ 
      Transpose /@ Transpose[{pts, sl}]));

ListPlot[newpts, BaseStyle -> PointSize[.025]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Very Helpful! Thank you!